# "A player must capture as many pieces as possible." What happens if he doesn't?

Tags: variants, checkers

There's a rule that says "A player must capture as many pieces as possible." What happens in the event a player didn't see the move with the most captures, and makes a move that takes fewer? What happens in this case?

(Is it against the rules to be not too good in checkers and be unable to see the best combination? Hmmm...)

Answer (score 10):

As per the the [Official FMJD Rules for International Draughts](http://www.fmjd.org/docs/Annex%201%20official%20FMJD%20rules%20of%20international%20draughts.doc), if the opponent notices that you have not captured as many pieces as possible, they may decide whether the move stands or if it must be taken back and made again.

> 5.4. If a player has committed one of the following irregularities, his opponent has the right to decide whether that irregularity must be rectified, or on the contrary, must be allowed to stand.

…

> 5.4.8. Capture by a piece, of less or more than the number of possible pieces to capture;

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the exact variant of checkers you're talking about. In the primary version played in the US, the [forced capture rule](http://www.usacheckers.com/rulesofcheckers.php) says that you must make captures if possible, but lets the player arbitrarily choose between capturing moves (emphasis mine):

> 1.20 All capturing moves are compulsory, whether offered actively or passively. **If there are two or more ways to jump, a player may select any one that they wish, not necessarily that which gains the most pieces**. Once started, a multiple jump must be carried through to completion. A man can only be jumped once during a multiple jumping sequence.

Comment: The OP is not referring to 'forced capture', but the international draughts rule: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draughts

Comment: All right. I'll add a note that those are the rules for the primary variant in the US.